# When the link is clicked it needs to be taken to a specific detail screen of my android app

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-studio-2.3

As if now, I have an app which has list of items and clicking on the item has an item detail screen with each item having a unique id. and if i'm sharing the link of the specific item from details screen eg. through WhatsApp then by clicking on the link it should not just open the app but it should take to the user to specific detail screen of the app.

Comment: Post some relevant code, that you might have tried.

Comment: you can make your app as a receiver of specific url, or even scheme. Then you can include any parameters in that URL, and after it is clicked - parse all parameters out in your activity. For example: `http://mycustomurl.com/settings`. In your activity you can get the URL, and parse it, and understand that you need to open settings.

Comment: Thank you for the response. As if now i only have the code in my manifest file which is able to detect the link when tapped and going to the mainactivity on my app. the code is as follows

 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data
android:host="www.xyz.com"
android:scheme="http" />
<data
       android:host="www.xyz.com"
      android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: Please, update your question with the code you've posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have this information in [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html). When you have deep linking working, creating the links will be trivial.

Usually in that use case the URLs created are real HTTP links, so you can have a server that responds to the URL in case the user doesn't have the app installed, so at least can see a fallback page with some information and usually a link to the relevant app stores.

Comment: Thank you for the response Xavier. form the above material of android documentation i'm able to get the app started with the help of code in manifest file, but still that does not open the respective screen though!

Comment: I understand that the list of items that you mention in your question is native (RecyclerView or ListView). Can you share the code?